# How to find the recession direction of a given system?

Tags: linear-programming

I have the set $S ⊂ R^6$
$$
\begin{align*}
−&x_1 +x_2 +x_3 = 2\\
&x_1 +x_2 −x_4 = 1\\
&x_1 −6x_2 +x_5 = 3\\
−&2x_1 +x_2 +x_6 = 2\\
x_1 \geq 0, x_2 \geq 0, &x_3 \geq 0, x_4 \geq 0, x_5 \geq 0, x_6 \geq 0
\end{align*}
$$

How do I know if $S$ is bounded? If it isn't bounded, how do I find two recession directions of $S$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's denote your set $S = \{ x : Ax \leq b\}$.
You want to find $a \in \mathbb{R}^6$ and $b \in \mathbb{R}^6$ such that $A(a+tb) \leq b$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}_+$. This simplifies to finding $a$ and $b$ such that $Aa \leq b$ and $Ab\leq 0$. You can find such $a$ and $b$ with the simplex method.